# Why do I get breakpoint exception at 0x7c90120e?

Tags: windows, debugging, internals

I'm writing a debugger on Windows. And I have this little useless assembly code I debug with it:

```
    global _start
section .text
_start:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, 3
    mov edx, [myVar]
    push 0
    hlt
section .data
    myVar dw 1234h
```

Of course it will crash at hlt.

I write debugging events on the console, after running and continuing twice I have these:

```
Process created.
DLL loaded: ntdll.dll
DLL loaded: C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
Exception happened.
First chance exception.
>>> 0x7c90120e EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT
Exception happened.
First chance exception.
>>> 0x00401017 EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION
Exception happened.
First chance exception.
>>> 0x00401017 EXCEPTION_PRIV_INSTRUCTION
```

Now the question is, why I get that breakpoint exception? I expect to get exceptions only for the privileged instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows debugging API always injects a breakpoint exception as soon as a debugger is attached.  This pauses the debugged application and gives the debugger a chance to access the application and do any initialization it needs to.

From the [DebugActiveProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> The system arranges for the first thread in the process to execute a
>   breakpoint instruction after it resumes. Continuing this thread causes
>   it to return to doing the same thing as before the debugger is
>   attached.

Comment: Does this happen even if the debugger CreateProcess the debuggee with DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS creation flag? My program is based on the tutorial I read [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43682/Writing-a-basic-Windows-debugger).

Comment: Yes it does.  And your linked tutorial mentions this as well in the paragraph above "Winding up..."

Comment: I only ran across the tutorial and I haven't read everything. Thanks.